# how to create custom login url drupal in simple way?

Tags: drupal

I have created a site in drupal, default login url is mydomain.com/user

I didn't find plugin or extension drupal to create custom login url.

is there any plugin, extension or simple coding to create custom login url?

Comment: Have you searched google for source code for login forms? You'd be surprised

Comment: Print login form as any other:

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106169/how-to-print-login-form-on-page

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

in hook_menu you can add this path menu:

```
$items["compte/%user"] = array(
    'title' => 'Mes informations de connexion',
    'description' =>  'Mes informations de connexion',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' =>array('user_profile_form',1),
    'access arguments' => array('change own username'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'user'),
    'weight' => 4,
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to have it accessible from another URL is to just create an alias for the current one. This doesn't make /user path invalid though if you're doing it for security reasons, but it does make a new path work for login.